# How to pass DateTime to Controller action

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I pass a DateTime from javascript to my controller action?

I get a Jsonresult with a DateTime in it for displaying a list of x number of items. Now I want to pass in the last DateTime to get the next number of x items. How do I give the DateTime to correct way? Should I format it someway?

Answer (score 0):

If your controller is accepting a DateTime type, then as long as you are posting it in a way that .NET can convert it using its ModelBinder (i.e. `DateTime.Parse`), it should work.

Comment: Well, im asking because when I place it on the screen, i also get other info like the day. But how should it work with UTC etc.?